# why can't I do something like 'echo xx | cd'

Tags: shell, pipe

Like in the title:

```
cd mypath
```

.. ok..

```
echo mypath | cd
```

why something like that doesn't work?

(I don't need that for anything, just curiosity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `cd` doesn't read parameters from standard-in, it takes them as arguments.

However you could do this...

```
cd `echo mypath`
```

Which uses backticks (``) to resolve echo mypath into a string and pass that as an argument to cd.

I presume you are trying to use something more elaborate than echo of course, because the above is exactly equivalent to `cd mypath`.

For further info look up "pipelining".  The pipe operator "|" takes the standard-out text stream from one process and feeds it into the standard-in stream of another.  `cd` simply does not read from it's standard-in stream, that's all.